# How to pass parameter id in a modal?

Tags: javascript, jsp, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a form that i wants to do update inside a modal. The problem is i cant get the parameter id inside the modal. I use this javascript but i just get the href attribut for the first click but not in a second click.

This is my button

```
<a href="StaffController?action=UpdatePassword&staffid=<c:out value="${staff.staff_id}" />" class="btn btn-success btn-sm updatepassword" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                          <span data-feather="user-check"></span>
</a>
```

This is my javascript

```
<script>
    $('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
         var href = $('.updatepassword').attr('href');
         $('.fetched-data').val(href);
        })
</script>
```

This is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Set Password</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" id ="update-password-form" action="StaffController">
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control fetched-data" id="staff_id" name="staff_id" value="<c:out value="${staff.staff_id}" />">
            <input type="password" name="staff_password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is the question tagged [java] ?

Comment: sorry my fault i have edited.

Comment: try adding `id='exampleModal'` in your button